# DOMCrawler truncates tags inside text()

Tags: php, domcrawler

I have a text with internal custom tags

```
$html = '<textarea name="main"><customtag>Hello World!</customtag></textarea>'

$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$text = $crawler->filter('textarea[name="main"]')->text();

print_r($text);
```

But DOMCrawler truncates these tags in the output

```
Hello World!
```

Why? And how to do that DOMCrawler leave custom tags?

Comment: The method is called `text` because it gives you `text` not `html`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to preserve child html tags then you need to us use the `html()` method like so:

```
$html = $crawler->filter('textarea[name="main"]')->html();
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html and http://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_html